# duplicate select2 ajax with same class name and same data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

```js
$(".medicine_list_ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/medicine/getMedicine",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchTerm: params.term,
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            return {
                results: response,
            };
        },
        cache: true,
    },
});
var rows_count=2;
$(document).on("click", ".add-record", function () {
var row="<tr id='row"+rows_count+"'><td><div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'><select class='form-control medicine_list_ajax' data-rowId='" + rows_count + "' name='medicinename_" + rows_count + "'></select></div><div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'><select class='form-control interval_dosage' name='interval_dosage_" + rows_count + "'><option value='1'>Once a day</option></select></div><div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'><input type='text' class='form-control duration_dosage' name='nodays_" + rows_count + "'/></div><div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'><textarea style='height:28px' name='instruction_" + rows_count + "' class='form-control'></textarea></div></td><td><button type='button' data-row-id='"+rows_count+"' class='closebtn delete_row'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></button></td></tr>"
$("#tableID").append(row);
rows_count++;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover mb0" id="tableID">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="">
                        <label>Medicine</label>
                        <select name="medicinename_1" class="medicine_list_ajax form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="">
                        <label>Dose Interval</label>
                        <select name="interval_dosage_1" class="form-control"><option value="1">Once a day</option></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="">
                        <label>Days</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="nodays_1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="">
                        <label>Instruction</label>
                        <textarea style="height: 28px;" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="instruction_1"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="displayblock">&nbsp;</label>
                <button type="button" class="closebtn delete_row" data-row-id="1" autocomplete="off"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a class="btn btn-info addplus-xs add-record" data-added="0"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Medicine</a>
```

This is a doctor prescription page and loads medicine from a database. A doctor can suggest multiple medicines. For this we have to load medicines via ajax using select2 and for multiple medicines we have to click on add record button.

This code works for the first medicine dropdown perfectly, but when I click on add record button the dropdown generated below medicine dropdown in next row does not load data from ajax and does not form a select2.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function and called upon after the add row is finished and initializes the select2 with ajax.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).